# Separate background map and rainfall data from a rainfall map

Tags: matlab, image-processing, weather

I have a rainfall map and I want to separate the background of the map and rainfall data, but i have no idea on how to make it done. Can anyone here give me an idea on how to do it.

I attached the rainfall map and its background below:

[image: the rainfall map]
[image: background of the map]

Comment: `map - background`?

Comment: As **hbaderts** said, but first make sure the images are the same size, and there's no misalignment( rotation / translation / zoom ) between them.

Comment: the think is the background is one of outputs, the input is rainfall data map(the 1st figure), the output are background (2nd figure) and rainfall data

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the background by subtracting two images. To subtract two images, both the images should have similar dimensions. Your attached images are of different dimensions.

`>>img_1 = imread('~/aV85G.jpg');`

`>>img_2 = imread('~/nGKKF.jpg');`

`>>size(img_1)
ans =
601   601     3`

`>> size(img_2)
ans =
487   566     3`

So we need to make sure that both the images should have same size and somehow img_2 has unwanted white boundary. To get-rid of white space and to match dimensions, lets do the following things.

`img_crop = img_2(31:431,84:484,:); %Crop image`

`img_rsz = imresize(img_1,0.667); %reduce size to match size of img_crop`

`img_subtrct = img_crop - img_rsz; % subtract image to remove background`

Above method works fine iff pixel values of rain fall area are different from pixels of that perticluar area of background image.

Comment: thanks for your help, the thing is the first figure is input and the second one is output that i expect

Comment: Its not clear to me, what exactly you want to extract from that image? you want rain fall area or just the background?

Comment: i want both, rain fall area and background map